# Excel VBA Application.OnKey

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following to run macro "SQL" when I press the enter key.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnKey "~", "SQL"

End Sub
```

But, I would like to run macro "SQL" only when in column 1 (column A).
Once the macro runs my active cell is in column 9 (column I) and I would like to run a second macro when I press the enter key in this column?

I tried the following, but the macro "SQL" tries to run for both column 1 and column 9?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then    
    Application.OnKey "~", "SQL"    
Else    
    Application.OnKey "~", "SCAN_MEZBOX"    
End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: do you mean you want to run "SQL" when you press enter when standing on Column A , and run "SCAN_MEZBOX" when you press enter when standing on Column I ? but on which worksheet ? all worksheets? do you have it on `Workbook_Open` event on purpose ? or not familiar with `Worksheet_Change` event ?

Comment: Is the idea of using the enter key that you want it to trigger after changing/leaving a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your "smarts" within the *SQL()* macro:

```
Sub SQL()
    Dim C As Long
    C = ActiveCell.Column

    If C = 1 Then
        'do something
    ElseIf C = 9 Then
        'do something else
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course ... brilliant, works perfectly. Thank you Gary's Student!

Answer (score 0):

You should write a central routine that *"dispatches"* to the appropriate routine according to where you are in the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "Dispatch"
End Sub

Private Sub Dispacth()
    Select Case ActiveCell.Column
         Case 1
             SQL
         Case 9
             SCAN_MEZBOX
         ' Add other cases if necessary
         Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```